# How do I get my LibGDX BitmapFont to draw?

Tags: java, libgdx

I've searched all around for this problem, but can't find a solution.

This is my render loop:

```
 Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
 Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

 batch.begin();

 BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/Media/font/myfont1.fnt"), false);
 font.setColor(new Color(1, 1, 1, 1));
 font.draw(batch, "Hello", 100, 100);

 batch.end();
```

I've tried all possible colors, positions and different programs for generating fonts. 
But the result is always the same: A black screen! (when glClearColor is (1, 1, 1, 1), a white screen...) Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I found the problem myself. It was a badly set up camera!

Answer (score 2):

Seems that uhave not loaded the png file along with the fnt file

```
 font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/billy.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("data/billy.png"), false);
```

**And please never try to load anything in render method. 
Try to load the font in the constructor or else u will end up with a G.C call and f.p.s will eventually drop down**

Answer (score 1):

You can initallize a new BitmapFont without having .fnt in your project.

```
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
```

then you render it:

```
batch.begin();
font.draw(batch, "Hello world", 200, 0);
batch.end();
```

don't forget that the Y axis starts from the bottom!

Answer (score 0):

```
 font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/billy.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("data/billy.png"), false);
```

If you have few fonts images for example billy.fnt, billy_1.png, billy_2.png you can just use:

```
 font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/billy.fnt"), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

create a .fnt file using hiero which is provided by libgdx website

set the size of font 150 ,it will create a .fnt file and a png file

copy both of file in your assests folder

now declare the font

```
BitmapFont font;
```

nw in create method

```
font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/rayanfont.fnt"), false);
```

//rayanfont is the font name you can give your font any name

in render

```
batch.begin();
font.setscale(.2f);
font.draw(batch, "hello", x,y);
batch.end();
```

this will work smoothly